# Unable to get to get EveryConnectionCollection for Internet Connection Sharing

Tags: c++

I am trying to use [Microsoft's library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ics/adding-and-removing-port-mappings-c-) in order to add port mapping to my ICS connection but I'm getting the "failed to get EveryConnectionCollection!\r\n" message. I am extremely new to C++ and I'm not sure where to start in order to try and get this working. I think I might need to initialize     `INetConnection * pNC = NULL; // fill this out for part 2 below` but I'm not sure what needs to be filled out.

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <windows.h>
#include <objbase.h>
#include <netcon.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "ole32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "oleaut32.lib")

// as in winsock.h
#define NAT_PROTOCOL_TCP 6

HRESULT DeletePortMapping(INetSharingManager* pNSM, UCHAR ucIPProtocol, short usExternalPort)
{  
    INetConnection* pNC = NULL; // fill this out for part 2 below

    INetSharingEveryConnectionCollection* pNSECC = NULL;
    HRESULT hr = pNSM->get_EnumEveryConnection(&pNSECC);
    if (!pNSECC)
        wprintf(L"failed to get EveryConnectionCollection!\r\n");
    if (pNC == NULL) {
        wprintf(L"failed to find a valid connection!\r\n");
        return E_FAIL;
    }
    INetSharingConfiguration* pNSC = NULL;
    hr = pNSM->get_INetSharingConfigurationForINetConnection(pNC, &pNSC);
    pNC->Release(); // don't need this anymore
    if (!pNSC) {
        wprintf(L"can't make INetSharingConfiguration object!\r\n");
        return hr;
    }
}

int main()
{
    CoInitialize(NULL);

    // init security to enum RAS connections
    CoInitializeSecurity(NULL, -1, NULL, NULL,
        RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_PKT,
        RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE,
        NULL, EOAC_NONE, NULL);

    INetSharingManager* pNSM = NULL;
    HRESULT hr = ::CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(NetSharingManager),
        NULL,
        CLSCTX_ALL,
        __uuidof(INetSharingManager),
        (void**)&pNSM);
    DeletePortMapping(pNSM, NAT_PROTOCOL_TCP, 555);
}
```

Comment: Please read [mcve]. There's way to much code here. A simple *minimal* example that we can copy'n'paste and compile/run ourselves to get the problematic behaviour, is the gold standard.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Sorry about that; was very lost and didn't know where to start. I've reduced the code included as much as I could. Thank you for the information and letting me know as well.